# QSettings value method returns wrong QString

Tags: qt

I have ordinrary text file with settings, which is generated by java application. Inside this file, there is a key `db.url`, which has value `db.URL=jdbc\:mysql\://192.168.0.101\:3306/dbuser`. I parse this file with `QSettings` class in `QSettings::Native` mode, everything is ok, but this `db.URL` gets messed up if I read it via value() method. Whatever I do (if I transform it into `QString` or `QUrl`), I get same result: `jdbcmysql//192.,168.0.1013306/user`. Why this key gets messed up?? I am using `Qt 5.4` on `Kubuntu 14.10` with kernel `Linux desktop001 3.16.0-30-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 12 22:06:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Here is a simple method that wrongly reads value of key:

```
QString UePOSSesttings::ueReadDbUrl() const
{
//    QVariant dbUrl=this->value(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_URL);
    return this->value(UeDefaults::UeDbKeys::KEY_DB_URL).toString();
}
```

and constants:

```
#ifndef UEDEFAULTS
#define UEDEFAULTS

#include <QString>

namespace UeDefaults
{
    namespace UeDbKeys
    {
        static const QString KEY_DB_DRIVER="db.driver";
        static const QString KEY_DB_PASSWORD="db.password";
        static const QString KEY_DB_URL="db.URL";
        static const QString KEY_DB_DRIVER_LIB="db.driverlib";
        static const QString KEY_DB_ENGINE="db.engine";
        static const QString KEY_DB_USER="db.user";
    }
}

#endif // UEDEFAULTS
```

Comment: Which OS are you on? Why do you escape ':'?

Comment: @vahancho, I've upgraded my question and I do NOT know, why string is escaped since I am NOT author of java app neither I have source of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QSettings clears up the string from unsupported escape sequences, in this case `\:`. Remove `\` slashes before reading the value or don't use QSettings for parsing unsupported file formats.

Perhaps not the most optimal solution but you could processes the settings file to escape all `\:` before reading it with QSettings.

```
QFile oldSettings("settings.txt");
oldSettings.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QString data = QString::fromAscii(oldSettings.readAll().constData());
oldSettings.close();

data.replace("\\:", "\\\\:");

QFile newSettings("/tmp/settings.txt");
newSettings.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
newSettings.write(data.toAscii(), data.size());
newSettings.close();
```

Comment: is it possible to use custom Codec or reimplement read/write functions of QSettings?

Comment: Yes, implement your own QTextCodec.

Comment: If you reimplement them you'll need to reimplement for all calls to value(), setValue().  Probably easier to have write your own function to do something w/ what QSettings thinks are escape sequences and pass that value to value(), setValue().  I do it all the time when I want to save values of something unsupported: QColor, for example.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic, can you provide me please with your example of QTextCodec, because I've never had subclassed it before?

Comment: @svlasov you wrong. Custom `QTextCodec` will not help to fix escape sequences. Because escaping is done inside `QSettings` and called before `QTextCodec` calls. You may research sources of `QSettings` to be sure in it. I spent a lot of time with same issue and my solution was to write own .ini parser.

Comment: @SaZ, you are right. I checked the source, `codec->fromUnicode()` is called after escaping the string.

Comment: @svlasov, thank you very much on hint, but `QString` class does not have `fromAscii` method (according to error returned by compiler).

Comment: @svlasov,  I've read the docs and it is obsolote since `fromLatin1` does same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I did it:

```
void UePOSSesttings::ueParseData(const QString& filename)
{
    QFile settingsFile(filename);
    QString data;

    settingsFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    data=QString::fromLatin1(settingsFile.readAll().constData());
    data.replace("\\:",
                 ":");
    this->ueSetParsedData(data);

    qDebug() << this->ueParsedData();

    settingsFile.close();
}
```

and now I get this url:

> db.URL=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.101:3306/dbuser

which is ok!